# How to map given JSON to DTO

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

I've the following JSON

```
{
   "status": "OK",
   "years": [
       ["current_products", "actual_tariff"],
       [ 2012, 2013]
   ]
}
```

I'd like to have a class describing given JSON, so that I'll be able to serialize/deserialize it to/from java object using `fasterxml`'s `ObjectMapper`. I've tried to use `@JsonUnrwapped` but the serialized result is completely different

```
public class ExampleDto {

    public String     status;
    public List<Year> years;

    public static class Year {

        @JsonUnwrapped
        public List<String> info;
        @JsonUnwrapped
        public List<String> years;
    }
}

// writing object to JSON value results to
// {"status":"OK","years":[{"info":["current","aktuelle"],"years":["2012","2013"]}]}
```

I know that JSON structure is broken, but how can I have a proper mapping for it?

Answer (score 3):

In your json, `"years"` is an array which again contains arrays of object, so your DTO will be-

```
public class ExampleDTO {

@JsonProperty("status")
private String status;
@JsonProperty("years")
private List<List<Object>> years;

}
```

**NOTE**: If you have json data, you can easily create correct pojo out of it here -

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
public class Dto {
  @JsonProperty("status");
  String status;

  @JsonProperty("years");
  List<List<Object>> years;
}
```

Then you can explore if they are int or strings.

Answer (score 0):

use some tool like jsonformatter-online.com which generate the  POJO class based on the json